# Azure select query gets slower and slower

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a table in azure that has +20M rows.
When I try to fetch e.g. 300k rows: `select * from table where clientId=2`
the first 30k get loaded fast, in a few seconds, but the rest take forever. Why does it slow down that much? The DTU when reaches 100% all of the time. I created all indexes azure suggested.
I have Standard S2: 50 DTUs plan

Comment: Please post the full DDL of your table including PKs, FKs, indexes, statistics

Answer (score 0):

To me i don't think it's an issue with Azure Sql database. It getting hung after it reaches 100% DTU.

In my opinion, the solution is to either go to higher pricing tier where you get more DTUs or optimize your query further.

Thanks,
Praveen